# HTML5 Canvas atan2 off by 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to get the green triangle to rotate about its center and orient itself towards the mouse position. I was able to accomplish this, and you can view the full code and result here:

https://codepen.io/Carpetfizz/project/editor/DQbEVe

Consider the following lines of code:

```
  r = Math.atan2(mouseY - centerY, mouseX - centerX)

  ctx.rotate(r + Math.PI/2)
```

I arbitrarily added `Math.PI/2` to my angle calculation because without it, the rotations seemed to be 90 degrees off (by inspection). I want a better understanding of the coordinate system which atan2 is being calculated with respect to so I can justify the reason for offsetting the angle by 90 degrees (and hopefully simplify the code).

EDIT:

To my understanding, `Math.atan2` is measuring the angle illustrated in blue. Shouldn't rotating both triangles that blue angle orient it towards the mouse mouse pointer (orange dot) ? Well - obviously not since it's the same angle and they are two different orientations, but I cannot seem to prove this to myself.

[image]

Comment: [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2#Description) "This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the **positive X axis**, and the point (x, y)". Your image is rotated so it points on the positive Y axis, hence your need to add `Math.PI/2`.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm having a bit of trouble imagining the x-axis in this picture since the canvas coordinate system is different from a normal cartesian coordinate system. Does atan2 somehow "know" where the positive x-axis is? (I highly doubt this but it's the best way to illustrate my concern)

Comment: Does this [interactive version](https://jsfiddle.net/0pgnq82m/) of MDN's figure helps you better understand what happens with Math.atan2 method?

Comment: @Kaiido whoa that's super cool - thanks! I'm mostly there, I just don't know how the x and y axis in graph there correspond to the x and why axis of the canvas.

Comment: The canvas coordinates is set to 0, 0 => top left corner, that's why we need to substract h / 2 and w / 2 to mouseY and mouseX, maybe I should edit the fiddle...

Comment: Here is [a version](https://jsfiddle.net/0pgnq82m/1/) using cartesian coords only, where the canvas' transform matrix has been translated to its center.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! I will try to absorb this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of how the `Math.atan2` works.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2#Description):

> This is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radians, between the positive X axis, and the point (x, y).
>   [image: A simple diagram showing the angle returned by atan2(y, x), picked from MDN]

In above figure, the *positive X axis*  is the horizontal segment going from the junction to the right-most position.

To make it clearer, here is an interactive version of this diagram, where x, y values are converted to  [-1 ~ 1] values.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  w = canvas.width,
  h = canvas.height,
  radius = 0.3;

ctx.textAlign = 'center';
canvas.onmousemove = canvas.onclick = e => {
  // offset mouse values so they are relative to the center of our canvas
  draw(as(e.offsetX), as(e.offsetY));
}

draw(0, 0);

function draw(x, y) {
  clear();
  drawCross();
  drawLineToPoint(x, y);
  drawPoint(x, y);

  const angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
  drawAngle(angle);
  writeAngle(angle);
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

function drawCross() {
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s(0), s(-1));
  ctx.lineTo(s(0), s(1));
  ctx.moveTo(s(-1), s(0));
  ctx.lineTo(s(0), s(0));
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = '#2e404f';
  ctx.stroke();
  // positive X axis
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s(0), s(0));
  ctx.lineTo(s(1), s(0));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.font = '20px/1 sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText('+X', s(1) - 20, s(0) - 10);
}

function drawPoint(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(s(x), s(y), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.font = '12px/1 sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText(`x: ${x.toFixed(2)} y: ${y.toFixed(2)}`, s(x), s(y) - 15);
}

function drawLineToPoint(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s(0), s(0));
  ctx.lineTo(s(x), s(y));
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setLineDash([0]);
}

function drawAngle(angle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s(radius), s(0));
  ctx.arc(s(0), s(0), radius * w / 2,
    0, // 'arc' method also starts from positive X axis (3 o'clock)
    angle,
    true // Math.atan2 returns the anti-clockwise angle
  );
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.font = '20px/1 sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText('∂: ' + angle.toFixed(2), s(0), s(0));
}

// below methods will add the w / 2 offset
// because canvas coords set 0, 0 at top-left corner

// converts from [-1 ~ 1] to px
function s(value) {
  return value * w / 2 + (w / 2);
}
// converts from px to [-1 ~ 1]
function as(value) {
  return (value - w / 2) / (w / 2);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

So now, if we go back to your image, it currently points to the top (*positive Y axis*), while the angle you just measured is realtive to the x axis, so it doesn't point where you intended.

Now we know the problem, the solution is quite easy:

- either apply the `+ Math.PI / 2` offset to your angle like you did,
- either modify your original image so that it points to the positive X axis directly.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate system on canvas works with 0° pointing *right*. This means anything you want to point "up" must be initially drawn right.

All you need to do in this case is to change this drawing:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXQJZ.png]

to

[image: rotated] pointing "up" 0°

and you can strip the math back to what you'd expect it to be.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), img = new Image;
img.onload = go; img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj9DU.jpg";

function draw(pos) {
  var cx = c.width>>1, 
      cy = c.height>>1,
      angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - cy, pos.x - cx);
      
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width>>1, -img.height>>1);
}

function go() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
  window.onmousemove = function(e) {draw({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY})}
}
```

```css
html, body {margin:0;background:#ccc}
#c {background:#fff}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: I have to agree with @Carpetfizz, I am not convinced by this explanation either. How the transformation matrix could point to anywhere? What does this mean? Math.atan2 method does return the angle between the vector and the positive X axis, but canvas transformation has nothing to do here. Some methods do also use the positive X axis, such has `arc()`, but once again, little to do with the transfrom matrix. *(But kudos for golfing this ;-))*

Answer (score 1):

When you do arctangents in math class, you're generally dealing with an y-axis that increases going upwards. In most computer graphics systems, however, including canvas graphics, y increases going downward. [erroneous statement deleted]

Edit: I have to admit what I wrote before was wrong for two reasons:

- A change in the direction of the axis would be compensated for by adding π, not π/2.
- The canvas context `rotate` function rotates clockwise for positive angles, and that alone should compensate for the flip of the y-axis.

I played around with a copy of your code in Plunker, and now I realize the 90° rotation simply compensates for the starting orientation of the graphic image you're drawing. If the arrowhead pointed right to start with, instead of straight up, you wouldn't need to add π/2.

Comment: Do you mean y-axis?

Comment: Thanks. So, is there a way to make my measurements so that I can avoid adding 90 degrees?

Comment: You could try `Math.atan2(centerY - mouseY, mouseX - centerX)`.

Comment: I've already tried that, doesn't produce the expected behavior

Comment: I'd have tried it myself first, but your codepen is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to achieve the desired result with a following axis 'trick':

```
// Default usage (works fine if your image / shape points to the RIGHT)
let angle = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x); 

// 'Tricky' usage (works fine if your image / shape points to the LEFT)
let angle = Math.atan2(delta_y, -delta_x); 

// 'Tricky' usage (works fine if your image / shape points to the BOTTOM)
let angle = Math.atan2(delta_x, delta_y);

// 'Tricky' usage (works fine if your image / shape points to the TOP)
let angle = Math.atan2(delta_x, -delta_y);
```